# SQL Error: The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql

This code was working perfectly fine, today I tried to execute it, and now I am facing this exception:

I have this SQL error :

> *Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The data types
>   text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.*

My code is:

```
  protected Boolean is_valid(string a, string b) {

   SqlConnection connection = getConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT [Email_id] FROM [logintable] WHERE [Email_id] = @a AND [Password]=@b ");



    cmd.Parameters.Add("a", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = a;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("b", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = b;




    object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
       ...
     }`
```

My DB fields type are `nvarchar(50)`. 
             `logintable` its just a simple table, i am using SQL express with VS. It has 3 coloumns, with nvarchar(50) as its datatype. and it doesnt allow nulls.

I have tried to resolve this error by changing `nvarchar(50)` data type in db to `nvarchar(MAX)`. but it didn't make a difference.

Also, I have tried to write my query like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT [Email_id] FROM [logintable] WHERE Email_id like @a AND Password like @b ");
```

but, it didnt resolve or make any difference.Please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761901/the-data-types-text-and-nvarchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator-in and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726649/the-data-types-text-and-nvarchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator

Comment: What is the schema of `logintable`? Does it have any `TEXT` columns? You don't open your connection and you parameter names are wrong.

Comment: sounds like you are not looking at the correct field or are connecting to a different database that has the db fields of type `TEXT`.  are you sure sure sure they are varchar?

Comment: its just a simple table, i am using SQL express with VS. It has 3 coloumns, with nvarchar(50) as its datatype. and it doesnt allow nulls.

Comment: yes, it was working fine previously, i didnt even change anything, only tried to execute it. @Hogan

Comment: better if you put it in the question.

Comment: Please tell me you don't have your passwords stored as plain text in your database?

Comment: lol for the testing purposes they are stored as plain text. type nvarchar. @joel  but thats not relevant here.

Comment: Thanks everyone, apparently my page was not redirecting properly. its working fine now.!

Comment: Security issues are always relevant.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I would say they are eventually relevant -- they become relevant at the point your site / application is hacked.  (If you don't make sure they are relevant prior).

Comment: thanx for suggestions! ill handle that!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "a" and "b" input variables are under 4000 characters in length.  Variables over 4000 characters are automatically converted to text variables by your ado.net driver.

Try changing your code to this:

```
protected Boolean is_valid(string a, string b) {

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) || a.Length > 50) {
        throw new ArgumentException("a is invalid");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(b) || b.Length > 50) {
        throw new ArgumentException("b is invalid");
    }

    // Do Work

}
```

Comment: i am using a simple username and password here. i dont think thts the problem.

Comment: Still, you should always filter your inputs (i.e. if someone pass a null value, your function will not work as expected)