# object doesn't contain any of suffixes defined in user-defined table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-types, user-defined

guys!

I don't know how to select objects that do not contain suffixes.
I declare input table of suffixes

```
  @suffixes  dbo.tvp_stringArray READONLY
```

And then I'm selecting my objects

```
SELECT [Object]
FROM [myUsers]
WHERE [Object] IS NOT LIKE (SELECT suffix FROM suffixes)
```

How to add '%' to the selected suffix?

Comment: The same way you'd append any other string? `... (SELECT '%' + suffix + '%' FROM ...`

Comment: But the IS NOT LIKE <multiple values> would not work. You'd have to use EXISTS or a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you can concatenate the % to the suffix when using the LIKE operator.

But to take into account the fact that you only want the objects that does not match any of the suffixes, assuming there are more than one, you could add NOT EXISTS like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyUsers 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Suffixes WHERE MyUsers.Object LIKE '%' + suffix );
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d20e4)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT [Object]
FROM [myUsers]
WHERE [Object] IS NOT LIKE (SELECT  Cast(suffix as nvarchar(1000)) + '%' FROM suffixes)
```

[Ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54343/1196295)