# How to add a string to a SQL result within the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
SELECT sum(qty) AS TotalItems FROM Sales.OrderDetails;
```

And this returns

```
+------------+
| TotalItems |
+------------+
| 51317      |
+------------+
```

However, I want the output to read

```
+------------------------------+
| TotalItems                   |
+------------------------------+
| Total items ordered is 51317 |
+------------------------------+
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Here's the query that I have: SELECT sum(qty) AS TotalItems FROM Sales.OrderDetails;

Comment: That type of formatting is usually done at the application level.

Comment: pls read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334/how-do-i-concatenate-text-in-a-query-in-sql-server

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sql Server 2008, then please try:

`SELECT 'Total items ordered is ' + cast(sum(qty) as varchar(max)) AS TotalItems 
 FROM Sales.OrderDetails;`

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: edited...........

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it worked. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and working with a database named: InsideTSQL2008

Comment: @KurtMorrison You are very welcome. I appreciate if you select the answer as the correct answer (by clicking the tick sign on the left), then other users who have similar problem and see your question find what to do easier

Answer (score 1):

Your database could be Oracle, and then you should try:

```
SELECT 'Total items ordered is ' || cast(sum(qty) as varchar(max)) AS TotalItems 
FROM Sales.OrderDetails
```

Comment: ANSI SQL answer!